# helm-mode-dired folder name completion selection without buffer opening

Tags: helm, dired

I use dired with helm a lot. Let's say I want to go to /foo/bar/baz folder. I press C-x d to start minibuffer prompt for directory. I type /f and I get 5 suggestions. When I C-n to the one that I need I don't know **which key to press to use that suggestion and keep typing the rest of the path**. Pressing Tab gives sole action, which is the same as just pressing Enter. It is time consuming and annoying to have to type the whole path.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is `C-j`.

Comment: It was right there in front of my eyes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @caisah said in the comment. To pick a suggestion from the list of suggestions in helm dired use **C-j** This will allow you to keep typing the path.